# automatic_uploads in tinymce returns null for iformfile?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, tinymce, image-uploading

I want to use upload image in tinymce.
my controller code and layout scripts is there:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> uploadFile(IFormFile iformfile)
        {

            //I upload my file and return location to editor 

          }




<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',

        automatic_uploads: true,
        images_upload_url: 'uploadFile',
        images_reuse_filename: true,
 });
</script>
```

But I receive null in my action parameter in controller.
When I debug the app and break point in controller action, Action called but receive null.
I use .net core 2.1. 
Every other plugins do well!

Answer (score -1):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadImage()
        {
            IFormFile formFile;
            formFile= Request.Form.Files[0];
            if (formFile == null)
                return Json(new { location = "Not Found" });
....
}
```